# VB.Net ComboBox (as Dropdown) not translating text to DisplayMember with Databinding

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I inherited a fairly large project at work that is undocumented and written in VB (originally started pre .NET, ended around .NET 2).  I'm in the process of updating / refreshing a lot of the code, but have run into an annoying issue that I haven't found the solution for yet.  This system utilizes a UI, a Web Service, and a SQL DB.

**Problem**: I have a Databound Combobox (originally set to DropDownList - I'm changing it to DropDown, which is what started this mess - going back isn't an option) that is tied to a DataSet that comes from a Web Service.  When a user types in the item they want manually, the data from the text field doesn't seem to associate itself with the DisplayMember, which forces the WS/SQL query to fail (it is sent a blank value when it's expecting a ValueMember).  If the user types in a partial selection and then chooses the value they want from the DisplayMember list using the arrow keys or tab, the query goes off without a problem.

**My Question**: How do I get the text field to translate to the DisplayMember which will then properly tie itself to the ValueMember which will then allow the query to execute correctly?  Sorry for making this sound complicated or convoluted; I'm sure the answer is easy and I'm just glazing over it.

The relevant bit of code is:

```
With cmbDID
    If dtsLU.Tables.Contains(reqTable) = True Then
        .DataSource = dtsLU.Tables(reqTable)
        .DisplayMember = "zip"
        .ValueMember = "gridID" 
    End If
End With
cmbDID.DataBindings.Clear()
cmbDID.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", dtsData, strDT & ".gridID")
```

I've tried changing `"SelectedValue"` to `"Text"`, which almost works - but it directly translates to `gridID` and skips `zip` which ends up with an incorrect Web Service response since the `zip` and `gridID` field values are not synced (`zip` (DisplayMember) may be 5123 while `gridID` (ValueMember) may be 6047).  I've tried changing `"SelectedValue"` to `"SelectedIndex"`, and that got me no where.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
To add some clarification to the process, the below pseudo code / description is roughly what happens.  I could post the whole module, but I feel that would just muddy the whole question even more.

```
Private Sub A
    FormAlpha is created with 1 ComboBox in the form of a DropDown
    This DropDown is populated with a DataSet
    DataBinding with a blank DataSet is added to the control to keep track of the users input
End Sub
```

lblSubmit_Click event is triggered on FormAlpha by the user after they have populated the DropDown with their data.  lblSubmit_Click calls Private Sub Submit

```
Private Sub Submit
    BindingContext(DropDown DataSet, tableName).EndCurrentEdit() is called
    DataSet.HasChanges() is processed
    If changes are present, changes are processed
```

**HERE lies the problem**

If the user has manually typed in the DropDown field, but not hit an arrow key or tab, then the DataSet registers a change, but returns a null value in all fields - it knows something was entered, but that data apparently didn't pass through the DataSet for the ComboBox (ListItems or SelectedIndex didn't change / fire I'm guessing).  If the user selects the item with the arrow keys, the DataSet has the proper input (I'm assuming the Data was validated by the control at this point).

```
    If the processed data is good, a value is entered into the database
    If the processed data is bad (empty), an error is returned
End Sub
```

If the above can't be solved with what I've provided, but someone still knows a better way to handle this type of situation, I'm all ears.  Rewriting the module isn't ideal, but fixing this problem is a necessity.

Comment: Setting the DataSource clears the Display and ValueMember settings.  Set the DS first then those properties.  Not sure what those last 2 lines are supposed to do

Comment: Suggested change made, thanks for that advice!  The last two lines setup the data binding for the control.  The guy who wrote the original code used an empty DataSet to see whether any valid data was entered into the dropdown.  Whatever is entered into the dropdown is checked against the items in the DataSource (DisplayMember) and then carried into the new DataSet as the DisplayValue.  To me it's terribly convoluted, and semi-hard to explain.  I could make a diagram though if that helps.

Comment: I dont quite follow, but to add a new item to the CBO, you'd add a row to `reqTable`.  It sounds like there it code somewhere meant to supply the new value when the user types in a new Display value -  I am not sure how  databindings on that controls helps - maybe a BindingSource using the underlying DT is what you want (a way to trigger the add process?).

Comment: I just added a lengthy 'story' type approach to help clarify what I'm running into.  The DataBindings on the control are used to pass the changes/additions between methods I believe.  The original programmer left me no comments, and his style is far from mine, so I can only make assumptions at this point really.  For some reason he used a DS to do what you're suggesting with just a DT.  The problem though is that unless the user is triggering an update to the actual DisplayMember (which apparently needs arrow key interaction), then no data actually gets sent. The text field is being ignored.

Comment: Every time I have had that kind of thing, I use an `[Edit/...]` button next to the `DropDownList` cbo - a small Dialog comes up, they enter some things, the code provides missing stuff like keys, update the DataSource (maybe DB as well). *et voila* there is now a new item in the list. In the end it allows unambiguous cues so no one is guessing at intent. (BTW, contrary to the name, DataSets dont hold data - they hold DataTables which store the actual data).

Comment: That may have just given me an idea.  He uses dynamic `DropDownList` controls on other forms to handle data when the data requested doesn't match what the form expects.  Maybe I can use that to help solve this.  It's roundabout, but it sounds like what you're suggesting as well (or, similar anyhow).  I'll give that a shot and see what happens.  Thanks again for the help!  I'll post back when I have some results (good or bad).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, while this fix may not be ideal, it is a fix none the less.

The bare bones problem was that the text value of the DropDown wasn't causing the data to actually affect the SelectedIndex / SelectedValue of the control unless you interacted with it using the arrow keys or a mouse click.  So, while the DropDown would read "1234", in reality the control saw "".

The fix I have in place for this is simply calling `comboBox.text = comboBox.text` whenever the user hits the submit button.